# Is there a way to create a diagonal matrix using only the matrix() command?

Tags: r, matrix

I already know how to create a diagonal matrix using for loops. I am simply just curious if I can get the same result with just one line like this:

```
row <- 5
col <- 5
matrix(data = if (row == col) {1} else {0}, nrow = row, ncol = col)
```

The desired result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

My current logic is to populate each element with 1 if row and column is equal, otherwise 0.

So far it doesn't seem to catch my else statement:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> diag(5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

Or if you must use the `matrix` function..

```
> matrix(diag(5), nrow=5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

or with `outer` (maybe closest to your row==col logic)

```
> outer(1:5,1:5,\(x,y) as.numeric(x==y))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

again with `matrix`, this is sort of what you were trying, the different `rep`s represent the row and column indices:

```
> matrix(as.numeric(rep(1:5,5)==rep(1:5,each=5)), nrow=5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 3):

To follow the logic you requested (given `n <- 5`)

```
> +(row(. <- matrix(NA, n, n)) == col(.))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

---

If you want `matrix` ***only***

```
> +(matrix(. <- 1:n^2, n) == matrix(., n, byrow = TRUE))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

or, you can try splitting the above into two lines if you are not used to the style `. <- 1:n^2` with in an expression

```
> v <- 1:n^2
> +(matrix(v, n) == matrix(v, n, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: Marvelously terse, but perhaps just a word about `.` in this context as it is rarely seen outside a *verse context (afaik)`.`

Comment: Nice illustration of code golfing/one-liner code, but the general approach is very fragile/dependent on making sure that sub-expressions within the expression are evaluated in the right order, e.g. switching the order to `+(col(.) == row(. <- matrix(NA, n, n)))` fails if `.` is not defined (and will probably get the wrong answer if `.` *is* defined.  In other words, this is great for learning about the language, but I would *not* recommend it as a general approach to R coding ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes you are right. This should not be a general approach. I used the sub-expression `. <- matrix(NA,n,n)` just to make things in one line, which was supposed to be done by two steps. It works only if the entire expression is executed from left to right, that's way the switching failed.

Answer (score 1):

R provides diag to do this but assuming that that is not allowed then if it is ok to use rep, c and * as well then

```
matrix(rep(c(1, rep(0, 5)), length = 5 * 5), 5)
```

giving

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

If replace, cbind and : are ok to use then

```
replace(matrix(0, 5, 5), cbind(1:5, 1:5), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @ThomasIsCoding's answer but a little bit less terse (and hence easier to understand):

```r
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
m[row(m) == col(m)] <- 1
```

This could be extended to other cases, e.g. `abs(row(m) - col(m)) <= 2` to create a banded matrix.

Comment: In quantum mechanics, annihilation and creation operators are sub or supra diagonals so setting the test to be 1 or -1 should accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `diag<-` function still written in R code. It appears you are thinking of just a simple diagonal matrix with all value on the diagonal being the same, but `diag<-` is more general and allows specification of a vector of value to be place on the diagonal as well as assignment to "diagonals" of a non-square matrix. When I got done stripping out the error checking, I just left in the parts that  made assignment to a square diagonal matrix of non-equal values, and now I get this:

```
diag2 <- function(value)
 # stripped out non-essential error checking
{ x <- matrix(0, length(value),length(value))
    len.i <- length(value)
    i <- seq_len(len.i)
    x[cbind(i, i)] <- value
    x
 }

diag2(1:4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4
```

The indexing is done with a two column matrix, a particularly efficient way to partially assign values in a matrix or array.